# iPhone iOS how to flip/reflect any UIView in - place?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, core-graphics

I know how to flip/reflect/rotate a UIImage by re-drawing it within it's bounds.

```
- (IBAction)reflectImageView:(UIImageView)imageView {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, -imageView.bounds.size.height);


   [imageView.layer renderInContext:context];
    imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}
```

But how do I create a "flip/reflect" effect for any UIView, preferably keeping it's center in the same position as before?

Thank you!

Comment: your question is my answer on how to rotate image :P thanks +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.activeView cache:YES];
    //        [self.activeView removeFromSuperview];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    NSNumber* isReflected = [self.activeView.attributedView.attributes valueForKey:kIsReflected];
    if(isReflected.boolValue)
    {
        self.activeView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
        [self.activeView.attributedView.attributes setValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]  forKey:kIsReflected];
    }else {
        //do reflection
        self.activeView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1,1);
        [self.activeView.attributedView.attributes setValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]  forKey:kIsReflected];
    }
```

Above code is used for UIView Animation. Where you will get an options for various type animation.

Comment: This plays the animation, but the view remains the same. If I remove the view from superview, there's nothing left in it's place. The animation is very cool, but I need to actually display the mirror image of the view

Answer (score 1):

You can make a "screenshot" of any View by

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

and then flip the UIImage and add a UIImageView with the resulting Image below the view.

Comment: I would like the user to continue interacting with the view, even once it is reflected. Displaying a UIImageView in place of a regular view is an option, but it may require too much user education as to when the view is "real" and when it is an "image"

Comment: What a great snippet! Still work like a charm 4 years later