# UIImage Flip Image Direction

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, uiimage

For a certain `UIImageView` animationImages, I wish to create 2 arrays - one per each direction.
I have png files I can load into one of the directions, and I wish to flip each image and add it to second direction array.

I tried to do something like this:

```
    _movingLeftImages = [NSMutableArray array];
    _movingRightImages = [NSMutableArray array];
    int imagesCounter = 0;
    while (imagesCounter <= 8)
    {
        NSString* imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"movingImg-%i", imagesCounter];

        UIImage* moveLeftImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        [_movingLeftImages addObject:moveLeftImage];

        UIImage* moveRightImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:moveLeftImage.CGImage scale:moveLeftImage.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
        [_movingRightImages addObject:moveRightImage];

        imagesCounter++;
    }
```

Upon the relevant event, I load the UIImageView animationImages with the relevant array; like this:

```
if ( /*should move LEFT event*/ )
    {
        movingImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:_movingLeftImages];
    }
    if ( /*should move RIGHT event*/ )
    {
        movingImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:_movingRightImages];
    }
```

The images are not flipped. They remain as they where.

Any idea how to handle this?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct orientation? Perhaps you can upload an image of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Use the .transformation property of the .layer property of a view given to you by QuartzCore to simply flip the uiimageview instead of the images

Comment: @A'saDickens, how should I make the flip? I'm not familiar with this feature... which of its functions should I use to achieve this mirroring?

Comment: @GadMarkovits, I was using the wrong orientation... I edited it. Still, the images are not loading correctly to the mirrored UIImage - they remain the same as the original ones....

Comment: If you want to flip the images programmatically, you will need to use the ImageContext functionality, if you want to flip the uiimageview so that you don't have multiple references of the images then you will need to use the frame work <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> framework provided by apple :3 i will comment links to show the 2 examples and you can pick the ones that look easier

Comment: oh never mind there is a simple solution

Comment: UIImage* sourceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"];
UIImage* flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImage.CGImage 
                         scale:sourceImage.scale orientation: UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];

Comment: oh but you tried that :x

Comment: you will have to try to look up information about GraphicsContext or the CATranform3D content of quartz core

Comment: @OhadRegev maybe you could try the code posted in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685422/iphone-ios-how-to-flip-reflect-any-uiview-in-place) question

Answer (score 0):

use this code for animating images

```
UIImageView * animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200,200)];

  NSArray *imageNames = @[@"bird1.png", @"bird2.png"];
  animTime =.0;
 [animatedImageView setAnimationImages:imageNames] ;
 animatedImageView.animationDuration =  animTime;
 animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[self.view addSubview: animatedImageView];
[animatedImageView startAnimating];
```